# List files modified for particular git commit

Tags: git, git-commit

I have commit, `abc`, and I want to list files that were modified for the commit.

What is the git command which will list modified files for that commit?

Answer (score 102):

For filenames only:

```
git show --name-only abc
```

To see a summary of what happened to them:

```
git show --name-status abc
```

Comment: for last commit, `git show --name-only`

Comment: To really get _only_ the names, also use `--pretty=format:`, which makes it omit the commit metadata. Then you can use it to, for example, re-edit all the files from a previous commit: `vim -O $(git show --name-only --pretty=format: HEAD)`. Or pipe the response through `xargs` and use your imagination.

Comment: handy review onleliner - open these file in sublime: `git show --name-only --format=oneline | tail -n+2 | xargs subl`

Answer (score 35):

You can see the files changed in a particular commit as follows

```
git show --stat <commit-hash>
```

Alternatively you can also view the patch introduced with each commit using the -p flag

```
git log -p <commit-hash>
```

BTW `git show` takes the same formatting arguments as `git diff-tree`, here's the [documentation for diff-tree](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff-tree.html).

Answer (score 2):

For anyone who'd like to have an output summary like this for particular commit

[image]

#### Step

1. Open your `~/.gitconfig` file
2. add this script under `[alias]`:

   `swt = show --pretty=format:"%C(yellow)%h%Cred%d\\ %Creset%s%Cblue\\ [%cn]" --numstat`
3. Save `~/.gitconfig` file
4. Simply run `git swt <commit-hash>`