# Configure git to not comment out the changes to be committed

Tags: git

When I do `git commit -a`, it opens the editor, in which the changes to be committed are commented out. I always uncomment these lines manually.

Is there a way to configure `git` to include those lines by default?

Comment: Why exactly do you want that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the default comments in the git commit message?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3966714/how-can-i-change-the-default-comments-in-the-git-commit-message)

Comment: @FelixKling May be because I do not know an easier way to get to that information than to look through the output of `git log`... (I am new to using `git` or any version control for that matter)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, you should see [how to list changed files in a commit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21515084/list-files-modified-for-particular-git-commit) then.

Comment: @fracz Great link! I do prefer "modified" and "new file" instead of the laconic "M" and "A", though.

Comment: git would not be very useful if you couldn't see what changed in each commit...  :)

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned in the various comments, it is not a good idea to do that. A commit message should explain, *why* you did something - the *what* is already in the commit itself and can be checked via `git show --name-status <commit>`.

Nevertheless, if you need this functionality, you can add this as a [prepare-commit-msg-hook](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks), which lives in `.git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg` and might look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
git diff --name-status -r >> $1
```

This will essentially give you a list of differences of the stage.

Comment: Using `git show --name-status <commit>` makes it a two-stage process -- first using `git log` to look up the commit ID and then using `git show`. Also, `git show` displays the cryptic `M` instead of the clear `modified` and the cryptic `A` instead of the clear `new file`. Of course, one can get used to these, but it is still an extra (and unnecessary) background processing in the brain. So, is there a way to make this information be displayed in a human-readable format when I do `git log`?

Comment: `git log --name-status` will print names and statuses for changed files, for each commit. Changing the M to modified sounds like a job for `sed`. If you want to get fancier, git comes with a graphical tool which you can access using `git gui`, and many third-party GUIs exist.